# Formula for row artificial shift

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, formula

i've been doing this for weeks but to no avail, i'll give you the context so it'd be easier to understand: i have several sets of warehouse materiel codes sorted from smallest to largest as well as the time they need to be delivered to the workshop for processing and the amount of pallets required at each specific time frame, here is how it looks:

```
Mat. Code   Time      Pallets
65504606    07:30:00    2
65504606    10:30:00    1
65504606    13:30:00    2
65504606    16:30:00    1
65504606    19:30:00    2
65504606    22:30:00    1
65504606    01:30:00    2
65504606    04:30:00    1
```

I'm matching this data with another worksheet containing the information on where each individual pallet is stored, so i need to shift values in the time column so that a specific pallet is delivered on time, here's what i'd like it to look like:

```
Mat. Code   location    Time     Cell shift
65504606    91-04-03/1  7 30           0
65504606    76-13-03/1  7 30          -1
65504606    97-19-03/1  10 30         -1
65504606    97-16-03/3  13 30         -1
65504606    76-19-02/1  13 30         -2
65504606    97-18-03/1  16 30         -2
65504606    97-18-03/2  19 30         -2
65504606    88-07-02/1  19 30         -3
```

I figured i could shift cells artificially by adding another column (cell shift - it has to be negative because the amount of rows in the sheet i'm matching with is smaller, plus i'm using INDEX - SMALL formula combination for matching each consecutive row of every set of codes), but all the formula combinations i've tried were giving me wrong numbers. The amount of pallets can vary from 0 to 9 and go in no particular order.

I know it's a lot of confusing information, but you would really help me out if you come up with a proper formula. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you actually need to do, and you don't show any actual formulas which might give us some clues.

Comment: You will need to restrict your range first with offset or something similar. Please tell me the time is the same, just formatted differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is look something up in a restricted range.
What I did was restricting the range so I could use a simple VLOOKUP.
What OP asked for was an additional input to use in another formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,OFFSET(YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A$1,MATCH(A2,YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIFS(YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A:$A,A2),2),2,FALSE)
```

P.S. Only works if the time values you look up are actually time values and not strings like the question implies.

EDIT:

```
=ROW(OFFSET(YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A$1,MATCH(WhereYouLookUpFrom!$C2,OFFSET(YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A$1,MATCH($A2,YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIFS(YourFirstTableWithPalletNums!$A:$A,$A2)),0),1))-ROW()
```

Then we need one more shift and then take the applicable row (we're still operating with ranges in this case). When added to the previously uploaded file it worked perfectly.

Comment: See [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6dVJPZ25KaDRXUDQ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, but i guess i'm really guilty of being too vague in what i need. The formula you offered matches the amount of pallets with my initial worksheet while this same amount is represented by the amount of rows with the same delivery time, for ex. i need to get 2 pallets at 7:30, so i need a formula that would either substitute the second time frame (10:30) with 7:30, then in the next row put 10:30, and in the following 2 - 13:30 - all in column C, or add a shift multiplier in col. D (cell shift). Again sorry for the explanation, i do it to the best of my abilities.

Comment: I did it OP! Edit: feel free to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how, but i guess you did, awesome, thanks! Gonna try that on another code set now

Comment: You restrict your range until it fits perfectly. It will surely be a heavy code but c'est la vie.